# String problem in Python (object does not support item assignment)

Tags: python, string

I'm developing the Hangman game in Python and I want to replace my word with  _ _ _ _ _ (underlines). I don't know the length of the secret word, so I'm getting the value with len(secret). But when I'm in my for statement a get the error: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

My code is:

```
def get_guessed_word(self, secret, letters_guessed, guessed_word):
    print(secret)

    for a in range(len(secret)):
        guessed_word[a] = '_' 

    print(guessed_word)
```

So, I want to replace/add in my guessed_word = '-' of length of the secret.

Comment: strings are immutable. you have to create a new string instead, or use lists. im guessing guessed_word is a string.

Comment: You can also simply `return "_" * len(secret)`

Comment: @markR yeah, but how can I work efficiently with strings in Python? Like to replace one letter or some letters in my Hangman game? I think Python is not better than Java or C...

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, you cannot update a character. This means `str` may simply not be the right type to store the state of your game. Use a `list` instead.

```
word = 'banana'
guessed = ['_'] * len(word)
```

Using this format, the `guessed` word can be updated.

```
def reveal(guessed, word, letter):
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c == letter:
            guessed[i] = letter
```

The guess can then be printed like so.

```
print(*guessed, sep=' ')
```

Comment: error: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: @l1den This is because you passed a string as first argument to the function, which is explicitly what you must not do